# Why can you replace $\sin(az)$ with $\exp(iaz)$ in $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{x(x^2+1)}dx$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking at the exercise VII.5.2 from Gamelin's *Complex Analysis*:

> 2. Show using residue theory that
>      $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{x(x^2+1)}dx = \pi(1-e^{-a}),\quad a>0.$$
>      *Hint.* Replace $\sin(az)$ by $e^{iaz}$, and integrate around the boundary of a half-disk indented at $z=0$.

I was wondering

> Why can you replace $\sin(az)$ by $e^{iaz}$?

I tried looking over the section on trig functions but I couldn't find an answer. I also tried thinking about it, but I couldn't think of anything. I know that
$$\sin az = \frac{e^{iaz}-e^{-iaz}}{2i}$$
but I don't see how this relates.

Comment: You can just do that substitution and take the imaginary part of the resulting integral to get the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've picked the wrong relation between the sine and the exponential.  You want $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} a z} = \cos( a z) + \mathrm{i} \sin (a z )$.  Do you see that you then only want to know the imaginary part of the integral with $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} a z}$?

Edit to respond to question in comment below:
\begin{align}    \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp(\mathrm{i} a z)}{z(z^2+1)} \,\mathrm{d}z &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos( a z) + \mathrm{i} \sin(a z)}{z(z^2+1)} \,\mathrm{d}z  \\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos( a z)}{z(z^2+1)} \,\mathrm{d}z + \mathrm{i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(a z)}{z(z^2+1)} \,\mathrm{d}z \text{.}
\end{align}

Comment: Oh right. I vaguely remember that. Except, I didn't quite understand when the book refers to the "imaginary part". Do you happen to have a brief explanation to what the "real" and "imaginary" parts of the integral are?

Comment: @Oscar The real and imaginary parts of an integral (over the real line) are nothing more than the integral of the real part of the integrand and the integral of the imaginary part of the integrand, resp.